# git permission denied on pull/push

Tags: windows, git, github, permissions, phpstorm

I'm trying to create a project using git, but after cloning repository from github in phpstorm i can commint/push/pull only once. After that I see the message about permissions denied on files: COMMIT_EDITMSG or FETCH_HEAD.

I set .git folder visible and not only readable and i can do one commit/push/pull and after permissions denied again. And .git folder become hidden and only readable.

In windows I set full access for .git folder and it files, but got same effect.

Cloning through phpstorm or console have no difference.

ps: Sorry for my english. And some names and title maybe not correct because I have russian windows.

pps: i've scanned my PC and found no viruses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push to other people's repositories unless they give you permission.

If you want to push the code back to github, fork it first on github, then do a "git clone" with the URL of your own fork, not the original repository.

You should then be able to do pushes to your fork.

Make sure you have configured your public SSH key(s) in the github account settings.

After pushing your changes to your fork, you can do a pull request on github so the original project can merge your changes into their repository.

Comment: I want to push on my repository on github. And of course i've create ssh keys.  Once again, i can push to github but only once. I need to make .git folder visible and not only readable each time when i want to push/pull

Comment: I never had that problem, maybe because I don't use Windows to develop - sorry

Comment: i have the same effect when trying to do only local .git repository. Commit once and denied after.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. First i tried identified myself in IDEA Jetbrains via userName / password and Test Connection confirmed the correctness of my input. But the comit and the push, etc. only worked with other applications. Not with Jetbrains. but now i used token variant. and that works.  :)
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FWI-41232